# Как обновить несколько атрибутов у модели

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Как обновить несколько атрибутов у модели на "+=1"

```
model.update("in = in + 1, out = out + 1")
```

Выдает ошибку `When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.`
Приложение работает на базе Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты передаешь строку. ActiveRecord не знает что с ней делать. Метод `update` ожидает хэш.

Выглядеть будет так:

```
model.update(in: (model.in + 1), out: (model.out + 1))
```

или так:

```
model.update_attributes(in: (model.in + 1), out: (model.out + 1))
```

`update` и `update_attributes` - одно и то же. Второй метод - алиас для первого.